# Is there a feasible way to invite flatmate to Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, support, sock-puppets

I rent a room, I don't need a whole apartment for myself and I prefer to save some money to party ;) Same with internet connection, we are rarely at home at the same times, so no need to pay separate fees for separate connection.

Now, if he will join SE, we will share IP. And I probably would feel the urge to find answers for his questions - he asks me questions already, only outside SE network. Given the ability to talk IRL, I'll probably spend more time on his questions than on anyone else, and the other way around. And there are votes.

Now - it seems it would look like sockpuppeting. I don't want it. And I don't want to get punished for it if I will not do it. But I understand there is no easy algorithm to distinguish it. Is there any solution except keeping him out of SE or moving out?

Not sure if it should be [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [support](/questions/tagged/support). Guess it's kinda both.

Comment: Don't heavily vote on each others posts, simple as that. Of course if theres something spectacular you could probably give them the odd vote here and there, but it should be very rare and a very very small percentage of both of your total activities

Comment: I suppose now this post exists, it can be used as evidence toward innocence... or are you just laying the groundwork? ;)

Comment: @danielhanly.com If so, it would be pretty transparent. We're not a court of law, is something is pretty obvious we act on it.

Comment: You could also not ask for his name, and give him separate advice personally. If you then come across his problem on SE, you can giggle to yourself for finding his account, answer the question if you can, and then not look at his profile page, in order to prevent looking at all his posts (And being tempted to upvote them all).

Comment: @Amber Drupal Answers are not a crowded place, and I will recognize projects. No way around it, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Molot Aww, oh well. It is a pity you and your flatmate don't share an interest in a much broader subject... I guess the solution then is to make him interested in a different subject where you can't answer questions about. I suggest knitting, cause that also gets you nice handmade gifts for the winter festivity of your choice! Unless you also do that...

Comment: @Amber there is a SE site for knitting? I used to know how to do it, too!

Comment: @Molot Unfortunately not, I think the subject would be too small scope, but there is a Area 51 proposal for [Crafts](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60509/crafts)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I expanded on this in [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194806/135615), but at the end of the day all decisions about what may or may not constitute abuse of the voting system are made by people. We only step in and act on the most egregious or obvious cases.

In some parts of the world, hundreds of people access Stack Overflow from the same IP. Many coworkers do, as well. Just being on the same IP as someone else isn't suspicious and by itself shouldn't cause problems.

We also recognize that you're a little more likely to vote for a friend's answer, particularly if they're working in the same area as you are. Where things get problematic is when rings of people on the same IP all conspire to only vote for each other's posts, artificially inflating their value. This can push bad content ahead of good, and reduce the trust that people have in the voting system.

As long as your friend doesn't exist only to ask questions that you answer, or only to vote on your posts, it's perfectly fine for them to connect from the same IP and occasionally vote for your material.

Comment: My main reason to kick him to Drupal Answers is to teach him how to ask good questions and to help him get knowledge from other people (more time for me!). In ideal situation I would never need to answer anything from him, but ideal situations does not exist.

Answer (score 9):

Just don't vote for each other (much). I live in a a university and many of my friends use SE. I just don't vote for them. Cross-answering is pretty OK, though it should not be your *only* activity.

If you want to vote, try to vote organically. Would you have found and voted for the post had you *not* known your friend? Then vote for it. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: With 11k rep over network I guess it's safe to say I would ;)